# Show fallback message when a video format cannot be played on browser

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am using `video` tag as below,

```
<div>
    <video ng-src="{{item.videoPath}}" type="video/mp4">
        <!--Below message will be visible when audio tag is not supported by browser-->
        <table>
            <tr>                        
                <td class="break-word">
                    <div data-ng-bind="::'NOT_SUPPORTED_MSG' | translate"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </video>
</div>
```

For my `mp4` videos, the server returns, `Content-Type:"video/mp4"` and they get rendered properly.

However, for `avi` videos, the server returns `Content-Type:"application/octet-stream"`.

And on firefox console, I see below error:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported.
Load of media resource failed.

Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: application/octet-stream
```

Since I already added a fallback message, I'm not sure why I'm not able see it when browser can't render the avi video. I just want to show the fallback message when some video can't be played.

P.S. At this point of project, the content-type my server returning is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use canPlayType, its a method of the HTML5 media (video/audio) object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType